# Python Categorize Dataframe Column Conditionally Using Regular Expression

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe:

```
group   id
A   009x
A   010x
B   009x
B   002x
C   002x
C   003x
```

How do I make a new column `new` that categorizes conditionally under the following three conditions by `group`:

1. If all `id` values consist of **ONLY** `009x` and `010x`, then categorize as `g1`
2. If the `id` value is one of `009x` or `010x` **AND** another `id` value is not one of `009x` or `010x`, then categorize as `g2`
3. Otherwise, just print the `id` value

Desired result:

```
group   id  new
A   009x    g1
A   010x    g1
B   009x    g2
B   002x    g2
C   002x    002x
C   003x    003x
```

```
data = {
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'id': ['009x', '010x', '009x', '002x', '002x', '003x'], 
    }  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can use `.groupby()` + custom function:

```py
def categorize_fn(x):
    tmp = x["id"].isin(["009x", "010x"])

    if tmp.all():
        x["new"] = "g1"
    elif tmp.any():
        x["new"] = "g2"
    else:
        x["new"] = x["id"]

    return x


df = df.groupby("group", group_keys=False).apply(categorize_fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  group    id   new
0     A  009x    g1
1     A  010x    g1
2     B  009x    g2
3     B  002x    g2
4     C  002x  002x
5     C  003x  003x
```